# Crear botones con *ngFor y *ngIf Angular 10

Tags: angular, web, ngfor

Estoy creando un sitio web eb Angular10 para a acceder a una serie de cuestionarios.
Cada cuestionario cuenta con una cantidad de preguntas diferente.
Mi intención es crear una pantalla donde figuren los botones para acceder a cada pregunta del cuestionario.
Si el cuestionario cuenta con cinco preguntas tendrían que aparecer cinco botones con el texto "Pregunta 1", "Pregunta 2", etc.

Si el número de preguntas es 6 el resultado tendría que ser el mismo pero con seis botones, y así sucesivamente.

He probado con el siguiente código, pero no aparece nada en pantalla:

```
<div class="preguntas_botones column" *ngFor="let cuestionarios of cuestionario; let i=index" ><div *ngIf="i < cuestionarios.numpreguntas">
            <button id="botonpregunta{{i+1}}" class="button">Pregunta {{i+1}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Si pudieras pasar el array de cuestionarios ayudaría más a mejorar la solución

Primero comprueba si el error no es este:

```
*ngFor="let cuestionarios of cuestionario"
```

Cámbialo por:

```
*ngFor="let cuestionario of cuestionarios"
```

Después creo que lo que intentas conseguir es hacer dos bucles anidados, es decir uno que pinte todos los cuestionarios y otro todas las preguntas de esos cuestionarios

Si es el caso deberías poner un `*ngFor="let pregunta of cuestionario.preguntas"` dentro del bucle que ya tienes y ahí dentro sí pintar los botones